# Help me to draw a diagram in tikz

Tags: tikz-pgf, diagrams

Please help me to draw this diagram in LaTeX

[image]
Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE! How can we help you? Draw diagram instead of you? Do you try anything so far?

Comment: I tried but I could not. I don't know to draw with tikz then I saw some models like level diagrams and trees, but didn't help me.

Comment: The site isn't really supposed to do everything for you. Have you looked at the manual? It has several helpful tutorials. Why didn't the models help you? If they didn't help, it is unlikely an answer here will help except with this diagram as a one-off. Will you ever need to draw another diagram?

Comment: Try drawing it with plain rectangles first - `\node` makes a rectangle by default. Don't worry about what the result looks like. Concentrate on getting the structure right. Then you can post what you've got if you need help with the style.

Comment: for start search http://www.texample.net/. There is great number of examples with code and resulted pictures.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

An alternative to your solution:

[image]

Main differences in comparison to your solution:

- as document class is used `standalone` with option `tikz`. With it you can see only images. When you are satisfied with result, you can copy code to final document or include it with `\input{<path>/<picture file name>}`
- style difinition is part of `tikzpicture` options (use of `tikzstyle` is now depreciated, instead it is preferable `\tikzset{...}`, where styles had to be defined on the same way as in `tikzpicture` options)
- for node style I rather use *mynode* instead of yours *node*. Use *node* for style name is not good since it is already defined in TikZ for node ...
- for shape of main nodes i select `signal`. Using it I avoid all your scaling of regular polygon and have better control on shape size
- in positioning of nodes I rather use relative coordinates to coordinate of the main nodes. in this I exploit `positioning` library. Their distances are controlled by `node distance = <vertical> and <horizontal>`
- for drawing arrows I define auxiliary coordinates
- arrows are grouped by `scope` regarding their common features (dash pattern, direction)
- not at the end, I write code in my editor and for shape data look into *TikZ & PGF manual, chapter 67 Shape Library, page 693* (shapes `signal` are described in section 67.4 Symbol Shapes, see page 713).

Complete MWE:

```
\documentclass[tikz, margin=3mm]{standalone}
    \usetikzlibrary{positioning, shapes.symbols}

\begin{document}
   \begin{tikzpicture}[ 
   node distance = 4mm and 16mm,
mynode/.style = {shape=signal, signal to=west and east,
                 draw, color = #1,
                 text width=1.3cm, align=flush center, 
                 inner xsep=0mm, inner ysep=2mm, font=\small}
                 ]
% main nodes
\node (A) [mynode=magenta]            {Text 2};
\node (B) [mynode=blue, below=of A]   {Text 3};
\node (C) [mynode=teal, below=of B]   {Text 4};
% coordinates for lines
\coordinate[left=of B.west]     (in2);
\coordinate[left=of in2]        (in1);
\coordinate[right=of B.east]    (out1);
\coordinate[right=of out1]      (out2);
% dashed arrows
    \begin{scope}[latex-, dashed, shorten >=1mm]
\draw[magenta] (A.west) -- + (-0.8,0) -- (in2);
\draw[blue]     (B.west) -- (in2);
\draw[magenta] (C.west) -- + (-0.8,0) -- (in2);
    \end{scope}
    \begin{scope}[-latex, dashed, shorten >=1mm]
\draw[magenta] (A.east) -- + (0.8,0) -- (out1);
\draw[blue]     (B.east) -- (out1);
\draw[magenta] (C.east) -- + (0.8,0) -- (out1);
    \end{scope}
% arrows with text
\draw[-latex] (in1) -- node[above] {Text 1} (in2);
\draw[-latex] (out1) -- node[above] {Text 5} (out2);
%--------------
   \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you very much @Zargo! Your answer and tips will help me learn more about tikz. Soon, I will be able to write this and others codes by hand. :)

Answer (score 2):

[image]

I drew with help of tikzEdit editor (http://www.tikzedt.org/). This is the code that produces the figure

```
    \documentclass{article}

    \usepackage{tikz}
    \usetikzlibrary{positioning,shapes.geometric,shapes.misc}

   \begin{document}

   \begin{tikzpicture}
   %--------------
   \tikzstyle{node} = [ regular polygon, regular polygon sides=6,xscale=2,draw, 
                        scale=0.5,text centered,text width=1.3cm,inner sep=0pt]
   %--------------
   \node (v1) at (-4.5,3.5) {}; 
   \node (v2) at (-3,3.5) {}; 
   \draw [-latex] (v1) -- node[above] {\small Text 1} (v2);
   %--------------
   \draw [magenta,dashed] (v2) -- (-2.5,5) node (v3) {}; 
   \draw [-latex,magenta,dashed] (v3) -- (-1.5,5);
   \node [node,magenta] (A) at (-0.5,5)    {\small Text 2}; 
   %--------------
   \draw [-latex,blue,dashed] (v2) -- (-1.5,3.5);
   \node [node,blue]   (B) at (-0.5,3.5) {\small Text 3};
   %--------------
   \draw [teal,dashed] (v2) -- (-2.5,2) node (v5) {};
   \draw [-latex,teal,dashed] (v5) -- (-1.5,2);
   \node [node,teal]         (C) at (-0.5,2)    {\small Text 4};
   %--------------
   \node (v6) at (2,3.5) {}; 
   \node (v7) at (3.5,3.5) {}; 
   %--------------
   \draw [magenta,dashed] (0.6,5) -- (1.5,5) node (v8) {};
   \draw [-latex,magenta,dashed] (v8) -- (v6);
   \draw [-latex,blue,dashed](0.6,3.5) -- (v6);
   \draw [teal,dashed] (0.6,2) -- (1.5,2) node (v9) {}; 
   \draw [-latex,teal,dashed](v9) -- (v6);
   %--------------
   \draw [-latex] (v6) -- node[above] {\small Text 5} (v7);
   %--------------
   \end{tikzpicture}

  \end{document}
```

Comment: bravo! you are proof for "where is a will there is a way" :)

Comment: First of all, THANK YOU VERY MUCH @Sebastiano for introducing me to tikzEdt. You were the only person who understood my question. Tikzedt is a great tool for beginners  and for those who learn by themselves.

Comment: @Zargo, I never give up!